# CMake generates "-L/usr/local/lib" on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, linker, cmake

I have a CMake C++ dylib project that builds correctly in one MacOS X environment but fails in another. Environments are on the same machine, but under different users. I'm seeking help how to do I troubleshoot where the failure in the second one comes from.

What I managed to figure out is that in failing configuration CMake adds the following flags in link.txt (the commands used to link the executable)

```
-arch x86_64

-isysroot  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk

-mmacosx-version-min=10.6

-L/usr/local/lib
```

The last one causes havoc as it makes ld pick up dependencies from /usr/local/lib instead of link directories I configured in CMake.

I would appreciate any insight what triggers generating the flags above and what is the best way to squelch them, especially -L/usr/local/lib?

Comment: Check your `link_directories` commands.

Comment: I did. None of my cmake lists adds /usr/local/lib to link_directories. BTW link_directories ignores paths with "/lib" at the end. See, for example, http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15706.

Comment: If you have two library sets with the same names but different locations, you should detect the proper library absolute path with something like `find_library` and then pass it directly to `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: That's one way to do this. Running each dependency individually through find_library quickly goes out of hand. What if you have a 3rd party library that has multiple dependencies, all in one directory?